# Zipkin with Spring Boot 2.2 and Hoxton Cloud

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, zipkin

I wanted to update my project Zipkin setup to Spring Boot 2.2.2.RELEASE and Spring Cloud Hoxton.RELEASE but it looks like simple jars update is not enough.

I thought the old setup (it was working fine for Spring Boot 2.1.5.RELEASE and Greenwich.SR2) would also work for Boot 2.2.2.RELEASE and Hoxton.RELEASE but it appears I still miss something here.

```
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.2.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/>
    </parent>

    <properties>
        ...
        <spring-cloud.version>Hoxton.RELEASE</spring-cloud.version>
<!--        <zipkin.version>2.12.9</zipkin.version> does not work either-->
        <zipkin.version>2.11.8</zipkin.version>
        ...  
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-zipkin</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.zipkin.java</groupId>
            <artifactId>zipkin-server</artifactId>
            <version>${zipkin.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.zipkin.java</groupId>
            <artifactId>zipkin-autoconfigure-ui</artifactId>
            <version>${zipkin.version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        ...
    </dependencies>
```

I'm getting the following exception (**java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: zipkin2
/internal/Buffer$Writer**):

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'webMvcMetricsFilter' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/metrics/web/servlet/We
bMvcMetricsAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'webMvcMetricsFilter' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'pr
ometheusMeterRegistry' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/metrics/export/prometheus/PrometheusMetricsExportAutoConfiguration.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is or
g.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'zipkin2.server.internal.ZipkinServerConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'httpQuery'; nested exception is org
.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'zipkin2.server.internal.ZipkinQueryApiV2': Bean instantiation via constructor failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: zipkin2
/internal/Buffer$Writer
```

Comment: did you solve this issue?

Comment: did you solve this issue

Comment: No, I parked that for now and did not update yet.

Answer (score 0):

It's a version problem. Zipkin officially recommends use `zipkin-server` instate of customer server after `spring-boot 2.x`.

For me, the `2.12.9` library works well under `spring-boot 2.1.8.RELEASE` with `spring-cloud Greenwich.SR6`